# BigQuery Spark connector: Wildcard tables or TABLE_DATE_RANGE

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I use the Spotify BigQuery connector for Spark (https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery) in version 0.2.1-s_2.11 to load raw Google Analytics data from Google BigQuery. This lib uses the official BigQuery connector for Hadoop/Spark from Google (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/connectors/bigquery) internally.

It works totally fine if I only load one table at a time, for example:

```
sqlContext.bigQueryTable("<dataset-id>.<some-table-name")
```

But I want to load multiple tables at a time. I tried to use DATE_RANGE functions and table wildcards which are provided by BigQuery SQL dialect:

```
sqlContext.bigQueryTable("<dataset-id>.<some-table-name-with-wildcard>")
```

But this doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
Invalid datasetAndTableString '<dataset-id>.<some-table-name-with-wildcard>'; must match regex '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'
```

That's clear because the specification of a table reference says: "[...] The ID must contain only letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_)[...]"

I want to load raw data as is, so I can't use `sqlContext.bigQuerySelect()` and provide a SQL statement, because then I would have to unnest the nested data stored in arrays (which I have a lot) because the connector only supports legacy SQL.

So is it possible to load data from multiple tables at one time without manually flatten it with something like `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` or wildcard functions which are provided by BigQuery itself with the BigQuery connector for Spark? Of cause I could load every single table one by one, but I want to avoid the overhead of fire a new query to BigQuery for every single table. So I thought I could load table ranges with one single query.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify why you can't do sqlContext.bigQuerySelect() to select UNION ALL all the tables together?

Comment: Of cause I could do this. But then I also could use `TALBE_DATE_RANGE`. The problem is, that the connector only supports legacy SQL. If I do a select with `sqlContext.bigQuerySelect()` I would have to manually unnest all the arrays contained in the source data (which are a lot). Otherwise I would get errors like `Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time`. But when I load a table with `bigQueryTable(tableName)`, I get the data structures as they are (BigQuery arrays are stored in Spark dataframe arrays) and this is much more comfortable and gives easier code.

Comment: Currently I don't think there's a way around it unfortunately, but it looks like the validation error is coming from the BigQuery Hadoop Connector (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/BigQueryStrings.java#L56), perhaps you could file a bug with them to support '*' in the validation since TableData.list supports wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Using a newer Spark BigQuery connector, it supports a wildcard table in a query. [Per the readme](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/4e50c95f90eb86f2ab46ae487ba27b1f54da9ab6/README.md#reading-data-from-a-bigquery-query) anyway. Something like:

```scala
spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled","true")
spark.conf.set("materializationDataset","<dataset>")

df = spark.read.format("bigquery").load("""
SELECT "bq-pubdt.stackoverflow.posts_" || _table_suffix, count(*) as row_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_*`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 desc;""")
df.show()
```

Let me highlight that query for you:

```sql
SELECT "bq-pubdt.stackoverflow.posts_" || _table_suffix, count(*) as row_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_*`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

Another fun wildcard query:

```sql
SELECT 
EXTRACT(year from last_activity_date) AS year,
EXTRACT(month from last_activity_date) AS month,
'posts_' || _table_suffix AS table,
COUNT(*) AS row_count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_*`
WHERE score>0
-- once yearly load in sept makes 2 year old data most likely a full year.
AND EXTRACT(year from last_activity_date) = EXTRACT(year from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 2
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4 desc;
```